# How to Add Standard Button in vf page salesforce

Tags: visualforce, custom-button

I have created a button "Make Donations" for an object Donations__c by going

setup-->Create-->Objects-->Donations__c-->Buttons, Links, and Actions-->New Button or link.

How to add this button in a vf page.

Regards

Comment: i believe the custom buttons are meant only for standard page layouts. you have to create a new command button in your VF page and replicate the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Sid May this would be helpful...

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.YourObjectName__c.YourCustomButtonAPI_Name__c, Id)}" id="Button" value="ButtonLabel"/>
```

Comment: Hi Amit .. If i need to open a vf page in a new window on button click.How to do it in <apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.YourObjectName__c.YourCustomButtonAPI_Name__c, Id)}" id="Button" value="ButtonLabel"/>

Comment: You can use apex:outputLink which have target attribute which can be specified to _blank to open the link in new window. But you need to use css to style the apex:outputLink to look like a apex:commandButton.